# Styling the text with bold and linked text, doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, styles

I want to style my content with some bold text and even linked text. I Googled as usual for the answer to do this possible and I found this [website:](http://android.okhelp.cz/linkify-text-link-url-in-textview-text-android-example/) . The funny thing here is that none of those examples works for me!

Here's my the code in About.java:

```
public class About extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("\"Vädret just nu\" är en webbaserad");

        ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 2, 14, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_app);
        t4.setText(ss);
        t4.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

}
```

`Vädret just nu` should be bold with that code, right? It isn't! I'm quite frustrated right now but I'm also new in this area. How can I fix my small problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work now! Here's the solution:

```
TextView t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
t4.setText(Html.fromHtml("\"<b>Vädret just nu</b>\" är en webbaserad tjänst och kan därför enbart visas i en webbläsare. Välj \"<b>Om</b>\" i menyn för att läsa mer om applikationen."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine at first glance. Alternatively, you could try

```
t4.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>\"Vädret just nu\"</b> är en webbaserad"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The HTML tags was not visible in the content as when I tested it before. But the text didn't get bold when I replaced `t4.setText(ss);` with `t4.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>\"Vädret just nu\"</b> är en webbaserad"));`.